# How to avoid downloading gradle zip file while importing new project first time

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am new to java gradle and using Intellij IDE for development. I tried many config setting to avoid downloading gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip every time while importing new project first time as a gradle but Intellij is still downloading.

[image]

I downloaded gradle setup(version Gradle 6.8.3) and did gardle variable setup but Intellij is trying to download gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip instead of using  downloaded and setup Gradle 6.8.3 version.

How we can avoid downloading gradle zip file?

Comment: Besides: **why** do you not want it to download the appropriate Gradle version? This smells like it's actually an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That project uses the gradle wrapper script, which specifies a **specific** gradle version to use, which is usually important to ensure that all plugins and configuration works as intended and the builds are reproducible.

It is therefore not suggested to blindly use a different Gradle version (unless you're willing to update the build scripts as necessary).

That being said, you can change what Gradle installation IDEA uses in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle.

Change the dropdown "Use Gradle from" to "specified location" and select your Gradle installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your own local gradle installation in IJ in file->settings.

Use Gradle From "specified location" -> your local gradle directory, click ok

[image]